How can I implement the PKCE authentication using Oauth2 in angular application
I have an angular application with the page login , when I click the login button I want to redirect the application into OAuth provider login page from there I enter the credential and clicking ok it will redirect to another web URL, how to implement this with the OAuth 2.0 authentication with PKCE
I am calling the initCodeFlow functionality in the OAuthService, but there is no request happening after calling this function, that's why the application not redirecting the oAuthprovider consent page
this.oauthService.configure(
  {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin ,
  clientId: '244913259722-u4jljhdtqp8rl13idp7cffbggsc5crm9.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  responseType: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email',
  showDebugInformation: true,
}

);
this configuration object passing to the service
this is the url's conifgured in the google oauth provider
